# sample RTSP SET_PARAMETER response

Tags: response, rtsp

I was trying to packetize and parse the different rtsp request and responses. Now I am trying with rtsp `SET_PARAMETER` Requests. I wanted to know how an rtsp `set_parameter (success)` response looks like. In the rtsp specification the given example was

```
  C->S: SET_PARAMETER rtsp://example.com/media.mp4 RTSP/1.0
        CSeq: 10
        Content-length: 20
        Content-type: text/parameters

        barparam: barstuff

  S->C: RTSP/1.0 451 Invalid Parameter
        CSeq: 10
        Content-length: 10
        Content-type: text/parameters

        barparam
```

This is the case where the parameter requested was an invalid one. I'm looking for a successful `rtsp 200 ok` response. If somebody knows how it looks, please help me. I tried a google search, but I didn't get any useful results.

Answer (score 1):

For example a valid RTSP response from an AirPort Express to a SET_PARAMETER(volume) looks like this:

```
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
Server: AirTunes/105.1
CSeq: 5
(empty line)
```

Note that `(empty line)` is just an empty line, not the literal string. The stackoverflow formatting just removes a trailing empty line. There is *no* body in the response.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example taken from [here](http://www.axis.com/files/manuals/vapix_video_streaming_52937_en_1307.pdf)

Valid Request:

```
SET_PARAMETER rtsp://myserver/axis-media/media.amp RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 7
Session: 12345678
Content-Type: text/parameters
Content-Length: 19
```

Response:

```
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 7
Session: 12345678
Date: Wed, 16 Jul 2008 13:01:25 GMT
```

And

Invalid Request:

```
SET_PARAMETER rtsp://myserver/axis-media/media.amp RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 7
Session: 12345678
Require: com.axis.parameters-in-header
```

Response:

```
RTSP/1.0 551 Option not supported
CSeq: 7
Session: 12345678
Unsupported: com.axis.parameters-in-header
Date: Wed, 16 Jul 2008 13:01:24 GMT
```